# Pokemon go - Lure Pokemon spawn time

Tags: pokemon-go

I want to be clear, I am not asking how long a lure last (30 min). I'm asking; starting from the time that a Pokemon spawns from a lure how much time do I have to catch it before it disappears? Is it a set amount of time? Does it vary and if so what seems to be the average amount of time?

Comment: Afaik, there is no fix amount of time of appearing and disappearing pokemons. Its totally random as some time i can see pokemon in every after 2 min and some time till 10 min nothing so no fix time.

Comment: I think the rarity of the pokemon may have an impact, but I could be wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lures last for 30 minutes.

From there, approximately six Pokemon will spawn on a Lure through its lifetime. Therefore, a Lured Pokemon will typically stay available for around five minutes.

Note that this is affected by Pokemon rarity and other random factors, very much in the same way Incense spawns Pokemon.

Answer (score 0):

The consensus in [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272549/how-long-does-a-pok%C3%A9mon-stay-in-one-location) is that Pokemon are generally around for 15 minutes. This seems reasonable for a lure as well, as they spawn every five minutes, and I usually see two-three Pokemon at a spot that has had a lure on it for a while.